# calling method of superview from subview when a button is pressed on subview

Tags: objective-c

I have a viewcontroller , onto which i m drawing uiview ,on this uiview there is a button . I want when this button is pressed a method is called on parent view controller that will draw a tablview onto viewcontroller

```
calenderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(405, 230,[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"].size.width, [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"].size.height)];
calenderView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"]];
```

Comment: i have a viewcontroller , onto which i m drawing uiview ,on this uiview there is a button . I want when this button is pressed a method is called on parent view controller that will draw a tablview onto viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self.view superview] methodname];
```

Hope this helps...